# Is there any way to make React Material-UI radio buttons required

Tags: reactjs, radio-button, material-ui, required

I'm new at React JS. currently I'm using Material-UI for building small reusable components. Is there any way to make Material-UI radio buttons required?

like an input field showing "This field is required" text when empty

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use name property and add the required property to radio component (change the values to your value property):

```
<RadioGroup name="nameRadio" value={''}>
    <FormControlLabel
          value={'value1'}
          control={<Radio required={true} />}
          label={'Label 1'}
        />
     <FormControlLabel
          value={'value2'}
          control={<Radio required={true} />}
          label={'Label 2'}
        />
  </RadioGroup>
```

Answer (score -3):

Assuming that you have multiple radio buttons, you can make one of them selected by default.
In the end, radio buttons indicate a choice, the user must choose one of them.

If this does not feel right to you, you can do custom validation.

Comment: Not sure why this is the accepted answer. @dtelaroli provides exactly what was asked for, without having to do "custom validation".